# How to convert kmz raster with rotation to GeoTiff?

Tags: qgis, google-earth, gdal-translate

I have a map that I have georeferenced in Google Earth and I'd like to easily use it in QGIS. The problem is that this map does not have north at the top, so the georeferencing involves rotating the image in Google Earth.

There are multiple answers here, elsewhere, and web sites for converting a kmz (saved from Google Earth) into a GeoTiff, but I haven't found one that works if the raster file has been rotated in Google Earth. `gdal_translate` seems to ignore the rotation parameter that Google Earth saves in the kmz or kml file. Also, if you just import the kmz as a layer into QGIS it also comes in unrotated.

Clearly a solution is to do the georeferencing in QGIS, but I was wondering if anyone knows a faster solution.